# reading all the file content in directory

Tags: python, io

I have directory `poem` which contains 50 files and I want to read them all.

```
for file in os.listdir("/home/ubuntu/Desktop/temp/poem"):
    print file
    f = open(file, 'r')
    print f.read()
    f.close()
```

This code reads file name of all the files in directory. 
But it fails at

```
f = open(file, 'r')
```

saying

```
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '32'
```

Comment: `os.listdir` doesn't return the full path to the files.

Answer (score 10):

`os.listdir` only returns filenames, to get the full path you need to join that filename with the folder you're reading:

```
folder = "/home/ubuntu/Desktop/temp/poem"
for file in os.listdir(folder):
    print file
    filepath = os.path.join(folder, file)
    f = open(filepath, 'r')
    print f.read()
    f.close()
```

Answer (score 1):

you are searching file in current join file path with directory folder.

```
import os

for i in os.listdir("/home/ubuntu/Desktop/temp/poem"):
    if os.path.isfile(os.path.join("/home/ubuntu/Desktop/temp/poem",i)):
        print os.path.join("/home/ubuntu/Desktop/temp/poem",i)
        f=open(os.path.join("/home/ubuntu/Desktop/temp/poem",i),"r")
        print f.readlines()
        f.close()
```